# How to merge Map<String, Int> with group by : Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, rdd

I have a data frame df : `[id, value : map<string, int>]`

```
id :1
value : ("item1" -> 2)

id :1
value : ("item2" -> 3)
```

How do I merge the map based on id, so that I can get

```
id : 1
value : { "item1" : 2, "item2" : 3}
```

Is there any utility function I can use or can someone tell me a better way to do this ?

I tried with reduceByKey

```
case class Data (itemMap : Map[String, Int]) extends Serializable

 df.map{
    case r =>
    val id = r.getAs[String]("id")
    val Value = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]("value")

    (id, Value)

}.reduceByKey((x, y) => x ++ y).map{
      case (k, v) =>
        (k, JacksonUtil.toJson(Data(v)))
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Since you added the group--by tag you clearly know of that. How might you use ut?

Comment: I tried reduceByKey by converting the df to rdd but that takes forever to run. I am not sure how to do this with groupBy

Comment: seems like df to rdd with reduceByKey would be more appropriate since your data is not very tabular.

Comment: reduceByKey is probably as good as you're going to get. Your problem inherently requires moving stuff between partitions, it's not going to be fast. Show your code, though, in case there's something that can be done.

Comment: maybe you could try first flattening the hashmap with an rdd, so you get [(id,"item1",2), (id,"item1a",3),(id, "item2", 3)] - mapping is fast, shuffling is slow -  then you can convert to df to get better performance and use the df group by functionality.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Updated with my code

Comment: @rado Can you explain your logic ?

Comment: It identical to http://stackoverflow.com/q/40073047/6022341, isn't it?

Comment: @LostInOverflow Yeah That question was just to understand either to use group by or reduce by. This is mainly to explore different group by options